# Group columns in dataframe, Multiindex pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am calculating some correlations for a set of measures. [image: dataframe]

For each measure, I have a data frame of the look attached, which I will join in one data frame.

I want to add multilevel indexing, with the name of the measure, above the columns I have.  What is the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `corr` to find the correlations within your columns

```
df.corr()
```

Use this to split CI95% column into two columns

```
df[['CI95%_1','CI95%_2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['CI95%'].tolist(), index= df.index)
```

Then use `corr()`